# Change field names in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, fields-attributes, spatial-view

I am building a spatial view using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. One of the tables I am using to build this view has field names that are not compatible with esri; the field names have slashes, hyphens and spaces.

Is it possible to rename the fields of the view being created as the view is being created? So something like;

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.NewView AS
SELECT * FROM
dbo.tableA
INNER JOIN dbo.tableb
ON dbo.tableA.UID=dbo.tableB.UID
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.NewView.Bad/field-name','GOOD_FIELD_NAME'
```

The EXEC sp_rename works if I run it by itself after the view has been created and on one field at a time, which isn't an ideal solution.

Or is there some way to run a find/replace on the field names of the view after it has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

Alias your fields in your select, and don't use the select * from when building views for ArcMap.

So your view SQL would look like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.NewView AS
SELECT 
tableA.field1 as field1Alias
, tableA.field2 as field2Alias
, etc. etc. etc.
FROM
dbo.tableA as tableA
INNER JOIN dbo.tableb
ON dbo.tableA.UID=dbo.tableB.UID
```

I'm not sure you have to run that procedure to change the names - my experience is the field name aliases do the trick.

Also - by explicitly selecting the fields you need, you don't run into any problems with ArcMap and the select * problem

ALSO: I've recently come across the ability to create a new table from SQL in MSSQL using the '**into newtablename**' method, and you  might try doing something like this instead of creating a view:

```
    SELECT 
    tableA.field1 as field1Alias
    , tableA.field2 as field2Alias
    , etc. etc. etc.
into dbo.NewTable
    FROM
    dbo.tableA as tableA
    INNER JOIN dbo.tableb
    ON dbo.tableA.UID=dbo.tableB.UID
```

We'll be using the 'into' method instead of using complex and time-consuming views - ArcGIS can take several times longer to compute a view than SQL Server takes, so by creating a static table, it is much easier to work with in ArcMap. And to update that table, you can simply add a 'drop table newtablename' to the beginning of the SQL statement.

Comment: @Cjd111 excellent!